# Determine coefficients of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

We are given the coordinates of $n$ points ($(X_1, Y_1), \ldots, (X_n, Y_n)$). We have to determine the coefficients of the polynomial $P(S)=AS^2+BS+C$ such that the value of the sum
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i-P(X_i))^2$$ is minimal. I have no idea how to solve this problem, but it seems to be very interesting. Any hints welcome.

Comment: I think [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) is relevant.

Comment: It is a least square problem; See the very pedagogical presentation of http://www.mn.uio.no/ifi/english/services/knowledge/cs/forelesn.kap5.pdf

Comment: In addition, the link provided by @JeanMarie explicitly gives a method to determine the 'best' quadratic polynomial (such as $P$ in your case).